# Unable to load images in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having an issue with using the ImageLocation of a pictureBox. I went to:

Documents\VisualStudios\Projects\Program Name:

Then I create a new folder called images  and within that folder i put the pictures(rock.png , paper.png )I intend to use.  Keep in mind I can not load from the C drive, I have to turn this project in, so that it can work on any computer. Am I loading my images in the wrong location? or Am i accessing them wrong?

```
if (PlayerOne == Rock && PlayerTwo == Scissors)
{
    ScoreOne++;
    picture1.ImageLocation = @"images\rock.png";
    picture2.ImageLocation = @"images\paper.png";
    lblOneScore.Text = Convert.ToString(ScoreOne);
    lblShowWinner.Text = " Player One Wins! ";
    picture1.Load();
    picture2.Load();
}
```

Comment: is this a winforms or webforms application..? what happens if you add the actual filepath location to the `ImageLocation` if it's web forms you want to use `Server.MapPatrh("`/images/rock.png")` if it's windows application you will need to put the actual file path.. also look into using `ResourceFile`

Comment: Edit your original question please. Don't add additional info in comments where it will be lost.

Comment: MethodMan I would love to use resourceFile but I can not find it on Visual Studios 2015 only for 2013 and previous versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VisualStudios/Projects/fileName/filename/bin/Debug/create images folder and insert pictures in that folder and my original code posted works just fine

Comment: Awarding the answer to yourself 2.5 yrs later is just weird. I thought "It worked out" with my answer and that's why you originally accepted?

Comment: If I added an answer, which I did.  It means it didn't. It is not like I just made up an answer yesterday, clearly I forgot to check this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the *ImageLocation* property, try:

```
picture1.Load(@"C:\temp\pic.jpg");
```

The picturebox load method also accepts URL's (if you can't access drives and it needs to work on any PC without hardcoded UNC paths):

```
picture1.Load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmIGn.png");
```

---

Or use the app's location if you have packaged it with an image:

```
picture1.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\a.jpg");
```

---

Or use a Resource file:

> I would love to use resourceFile but I can not find it on Visual Studios 2015 only for 2013 and previous versions

It hasn't changed from VS2013 to VS2015, in your Winforms project, expand the Project Properties and double click on Resources.resx, then add an image:

[image]

```
picture1.Image = global::ProjectName.Properties.Resources.ImageName;
```

Comment: See my edit, use a URL if it has to work on any PC OR package your app with the image...

Comment: Have you tried embedding the file and using it like a resource?

Comment: Thanks It worked out!  I actually had my images in the wrong section...VisualStudios/Projects/fileName/filename/bin/Debug/create images folder and insert pictures in that folder and my original code posted works just fine.  Again Thank you for the input

Comment: There is a holo checkbox next to each answer, ticking it gives you a couple of points and lets everyone know your question has been answered. Good luck!